# Can't make Angular.js to work

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to learn Angular.js. I set up a simple page, in which I want to display a message from my script file. Here's the HTML structure:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app>
<head>
<script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="2.0.0-alpha.31" src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-alpha.31/angular.js"></script>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainController">
    <h1>{{message}}</h1>
</body>

</html>
```

And this is my script.js:

```
var MainController = function($scope){
     $scope.message = "my message";
};
```

I'm supposed to see the words `my message` on the page, but instead I'm seeing literally `{{message}}`. I tried to wrap the JS code in self-envoking function:

```
(function() {
    var MainController = function($scope) {
        $scope.message = "my message";
    };
}());
```

But it didn't have any result.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You seem to be using Angular v1.x, but added v2 script. Also, latest versions of Angular v1.x do not allow global function controllers. You need to register the controller function explictly with `.controller` method of `angular.module`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's old syntax and you cannot declare controller like that. Now you need to register controller on your module.

```
angular.module('anyModuleName',[]).controller('yourControllerName',function(){
});
```

and also edit to `ng-app="anyModuleName"` where you initialize your app. In your case `<html ng-app="anyModuleName">`

Comment: this isn't correct either for angular 2 which OP has included

Comment: Yes, tried this and it worked! Thank you very much! Oddly enough, it worked on my localhost, but when I tried this code on Plunker.co, I got this error message: `ReferenceError: angular is not defined`

Comment: @charlietfl So what is correct? Just for the record, I did it in self-envoking function: `(function(){
    var myApp= angular.module("myApp", []);
    myApp.controller('MainController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
        $scope.message = 'my message';
    }]);
}());`

Comment: @Igal use latest version of angular 1 for that code. angular 2 is new and not released yet and is different

Comment: @charlietfl OK, just changed it to Angular 1.4.7 and it keeps working. Other than that, is my code correct?